# To drop or not to drop the s after the apostrophe (when the main word ends in s and the word has is being contracted)

Tags: apostrophe

If I want to abbreviate the sentence "Please fetch me the book; I think Jean has got it.", I can write "Jean's got it."

But what if it's Carlos who has it?

Assuming you prefer the style of possessives where you'd write *Carlos'* instead of *Carlos's*, is it ok to write *Carlos'* to mean "Carlos has" in addition to "of Carlos"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you were **saying** "Carlos has got it", it would be likely to be contracted to "Carlos 'as got it", perhaps even shortening the *'as* to almost a schwa.

What you wouldn't say is "Carlos got it".

Thus what you **write** is what you say: *Carlos's got it*.

This isn't a possessive, which has its own rules and customs, as you point out. It's a straightforward contraction of *has*.